# How can I make story same as Instagram

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing, swift3, video-processing

I want to implement a story(Image and videos) like the `Instagram` and `WhatsApp` application. Features like the add text on image and video with the customize font and color. Please see the below image for the reference 
[image]

Is there any idea? I have referred following like for [Add text on the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302799/add-text-on-uiimage) but not much help.

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext is the correct way to do it. What are the implications are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let imagePlaceholder = "[ImagePlaceholder]"
let fullString = String(format: "Hello %@", imagePlaceholder)
let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16), .foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString, attributes: attributes)

if let imagePlaceholderRange = fullString.range(of: imagePlaceholder) {
    let range = NSRange(imagePlaceholderRange, in: fullString)
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    let myImage = UIImage(named: "MyImage")
    attachment.image = myImage

    let stringAttachment = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: stringAttachment)
}
myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add in css or any phostoshop

if it is css means you need wotk opacity:0.5
add div on image
add the text